# Empty Partition Reported as Full

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, disk-space, ntfs-junction

I have a Windows 10 desktop with a 1 TB drive that I use for my OS partition plus one other 500 MB partition (mounted as E:) that almost exclusively has junction links to folders on my other drives (these junctions do exist in directories created "locally" on the E:\ drive).

I have a program that automatically puts these junction links on the E:\ drive and this program recently started failing because it says it does not have sufficient space to create the local directories where the junctions will go.

When I look at the space usage with TreeSize Free (run as administrator to explore all folders), it says I am using 18.7 MB of space (this is almost entirely due to shortcut .lnk files I created on this "drive").  When I right-click on the E:\ drive in Windows Explorer and select "Properties" it says that I am using up 499 MB of space and only have 4 KB free (which I assume is correct due to the fact that I get an insufficient space error when I try to create a new directory here).  Is all this space being used up in the file system table?

**My Question: How can I examine where/how this half a gigabyte is being used?**

I am on Windows 10 so I believe system restore is off by default but just to double check, I took ownership and gave myself permissions to look in "E:\system volume information" to make sure nothing was in there (and there was only 20 KB of files in that folder).  Similarly I emptied the recycle bin just in case there was space being used there.

chkdsk gives the following output:

```
E:\>chkdsk E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is SsdLinkPoint.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  272640 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 4.10 seconds.
  24 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.50 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  262396 reparse records processed.
  288946 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 3.38 seconds.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 118.09 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.43 milliseconds.
  262396 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 958.93 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 11.39 milliseconds.
  8153 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.26 milliseconds.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

    511999 KB total disk space.
     24288 KB in 264445 files.
    104668 KB in 8155 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    383039 KB in use by the system.
      4224 KB occupied by the log file.
         4 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
    127999 total allocation units on disk.
         1 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 8.58 seconds (8587 ms).
```

So it looks like the bulk of the space is being use by "the system".  Can I drill into that any further to determine how it is being used?

Comment: I decided to recreate the partition (and shrink another partition so I could expand this one).  I recreated the folders, junctions, links, and shortcuts after recreating the partition and interestingly, after doing this there was only 101711 KB in use by "the system".  I wish I could understand why this bloat existed so I could avoid it or remedy it in the future.  Perhaps this is a result of me periodically deleting and re-creating the files, folders, and links on this drive.